# Get the string in an span id tag, wehn running python selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I want to extract the word "In stock" from the element. The tag looks like this:

```
<span id="quantitySpan">" in stock" <img class="quantitySpanImg" src="https://d3m9l0v76dty0.cloudfront.net/system/photos/436808/original/34f362ca4ecee94ab2262e159a8ce432.jpg?1588592491"> <-span>
```

I tried to get the string using:

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, "quantitySpan")
```

but it didn't work. I tried by XPath but I'm still not getting the string.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span")
```

Answer (score 1):

found it :)

we can find the element and get all attributes of the element:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("quantitySpan").get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

then, we only need to search the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it might work

```
print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[id="quantitySpan"]').text)
```

Comment: It doesn't work... I've tried to add '.text'. I'm getting an empty string

Comment: can you share the URL or the HTML of the page if it's a public link so that I can provide some work around

Comment: the issue is that the URL page presents the tags only if you are logged in : https://www.visualdg.co.il/items/5720601-K513EQ-i7-1165G7-15-6-1T-2-8G-W11-SILVER-MX350-2G-1Y

Comment: I see, so can you share the "driver.page_source" of that specific page if possible?

Comment: I guess, your target span tag is deeply nested, that's why sometimes it can not be directly found from the driver

Comment: attached driver.page_source -  [link] https://file.io/5xW7wm2RlKSx

Answer (score 0):

Your locator looks fine but I don't see where you used `.text` to get the text from the element, e.g.

```
s = driver.find_element(By.ID, "quantitySpan").text
print(s)
```

---

It's probably a timing issue. You can just write some code to wait until the text is not empty string, e.g.

```
def wait_for_text(locator)
    while driver.find_element(locator).text == ""
        time.sleep(0.5)
    return driver.find_element(locator).text
```

and then you call it like

```
s = wait_for_text((By.ID, "quantitySpan"))
print(s)
```

Comment: It doesn't work... I've tried to add '.text'. I'm getting an empty string

Comment: @DvirYadae My guess is that it's a timing issue. I've updated my answer with a quick method to wait for the text to be filled.